# How do I make the AspNetUsers table temporal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables, asp.net-core-7.0

[As of Entity Framework Core 6.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/) [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) are available. In the example, the blog post says it's as easy as adding `IsTemporal()`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Customer>()
        .ToTable("Customers", b => b.IsTemporal());

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Product>()
        .ToTable("Products", b => b.IsTemporal());

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Order>()
        .ToTable("Orders", b => b.IsTemporal());
}
```

I created a new ASP.NET Core 7 Razor Pages application via the Visual Studio 2022 template with Individual Accounts for authentication (in a Linux docker container, but I don't think that matters).

In the `Data\Migrations\` folder, a migration called `00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs` is automatically created for you. I tried to make the `AspNetUsers` table temporal by changing this line in `00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer.cs`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser", b =>
{
    // All the column and constraint definitions

     b.ToTable("AspNetUsers", c => c.IsTemporal());
});
```

When I added the `c => c.IsTemporal()` argument as shown in the instructions and I try to run `dotnet ef database update`, I get a very vague error message:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')

The stack trace didn't help me any, but here it is for completeness:

```
Applying migration '00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema'.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.FindProperty(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityType.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType.FindProperty(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Metadata.Internal.SqlServerAnnotationProvider.For(IColumn column, Boolean designTime)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AnnotatableBase.AddAnnotations(AnnotatableBase annotatable, IEnumerable`1 annotations)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AnnotatableBase.AddAnnotations(IEnumerable`1 annotations)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.Create(IModel model, IRelationalAnnotationProvider relationalAnnotationProvider, IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.RelationalModel.Add(IModel model, IRelationalAnnotationProvider relationalAnnotationProvider, IRelationalTypeMappingSource relationalTypeMappingSource, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelRuntimeInitializer.InitializeModel(IModel model, Boolean designTime, Boolean prevalidation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.FinalizeModel(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

If I remove `c => c.IsTemporal()`, `dotnet ef database update` succeeds, but the table is just a normal table.

Comment: You should do it in the OnModelCreating and then create a migration, you are not supposed to modify schema.designer file

Answer (score 1):

The method call seems [legit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlservertablebuilderextensions.istemporal?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlservertablebuilderextensions-istemporal(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-ownednavigationtablebuilder-system-boolean)), so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

However, you can also override `OnModelCreating`, which, if possible, is always to be preferred over changing migration code. For types belonging to ASP.Net Identity, additional configuration should be done after the base call (although, in this case it's indifferent):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser<Guid>>().ToTable("AspNetUsers", t => t.IsTemporal());
}
```

Where `MyUser` is derived from `IdentityUser` with, in this example, customized to have `Guid` as primary key type. Of course it also works with the default (primary key is `string`).

This creates a system-versioned `AspNetUsers` table in the database.